# how to to use ElementTree to view subelements of a child in python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML that I need to print out the content of members, I am trying to do this using elementree but I cannot figure out how to do this, below is the xml:

> ```
> <response status="success"><result><entry name="TEST-ADDRESS-GROUP">
> <static>
> <member>TEST_1</member>
> <member>TEST_2</member>   
> </static> </entry></result></response>
> ```

Comment: What have you tried, that'd also be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data = '''<response status="success"><result><entry name="TEST-ADDRESS-GROUP">
              <static>
              <member>TEST_1</member>
              <member>TEST_2</member>   
              </static> </entry></result></response>
           '''
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
member_elements = tree.findall('.//member')
text_in_member_elements = [element.text for element in member_elements]
```